# Merge duplicate rows to one row from 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-update, sql-delete

I have found merge rows threads but nothing as complex as this. I have these 2 tables below. As you can see I have duplicates in my first table. I need to keep only one of the rows. But before I can delete any rows I need to migrate all the license plate numbers in table 2 to only first_table_id.

| id | VIN |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 |
| 2 | 1234 |
| 3 | 1234 |
| 4 | 1234 |

| id | License_Plate_Number | first_table_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1111 | 1 |
| 102 | 2222 | 2 |
| 103 | 3333 | 3 |
| 104 | 4444 | 4 |

After joining them on the id from the first table it would look like this

| id | VIN | License_Plate_Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 1111 |
| 2 | 1234 | 2222 |
| 3 | 1234 | 3333 |
| 4 | 1234 | 4444 |

The expected result would be this

| id | VIN |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 |

| id | License_Plate_Number | first_table_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1111 | 1 |
| 102 | 2222 | 1 |
| 103 | 3333 | 1 |
| 104 | 4444 | 1 |

| id | VIN | License_Plate_Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 1111 |
| 1 | 1234 | 2222 |
| 1 | 1234 | 3333 |
| 1 | 1234 | 4444 |

Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starter: here is a small query that gives you the mapping between the "old" and the target `id`.

```
select id, min(id) over(partition by vin) new_id from table1
```

With this information at hand, we can re-assign the rows of the second table to the target id with the `update`/`join` syntax:

```
update t2
set first_table_id = t1.new_id 
from table2 t2
inner join (select id, min(id) over(partition by vin) new_id from table1) t1 
    on t1.id = t2.first_table_id
```

We can then delete the "duplicates" in the first table:

```
with cte as (select id, min(id) over(partition by vin) new_id from table1)
delete from cte where id != new_id
```

Beware that the two queries need to be executed in the same transaction to avoid potential concurrency (ideally, other processes writing to the tables should be put on hold in the meantime).

Answer (score 0):

update the `first_table_id` column in the second table to reference only one of the rows in the first table, and then `delete` the `duplicate rows` from the first table.

```
    -- Update the first_table_id column in the second table to reference only one row 
UPDATE second_table
SET first_table_id = 1
WHERE first_table_id IN (2, 3, 4);

-- Delete the duplicate rows from the first table
DELETE FROM first_table
WHERE id IN (2, 3, 4);

---Here's the o/p

first_table:
id  VIN
1   1234

second_table:
id  License_Plate_Number    first_table_id
101 1111                    1
102 2222                    1
103 3333                    1
104 4444                    1
```